# Find the 2x2 matrix S representing this linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

We consider the linear transformation in a plane consisting of the symmetry with regards to the line $L$: $ax + by = 0$

Each point $M=(x, y)$ of the plane is sent to its symmetric point across line (L).

$M=(x,y) \to M'=(x',y')$  such that line $MM'$ is orthogonal to $L$ and the distances $MN$ and $M'N$ are equal where $N$ is the intersect between line $MM'$ and line $L$

Find the $2\times 2$ matrix $S$ representing this linear transformation.

(Hint: first find a set of orthonormal eigenvectors of the transformation and their eigenvalues. Then write matrix $S$ as the product of $PDP'$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $P'$ is the transpose of $P$.)

Comment: I think the best way for your learning process is to actually study an example. Random examples usually produce bad images for the point, but here is one that comes out nice: reflection line is $y=2x$ and the point is $(3,1)$. It is mapped onto $(-1,3)$. Why don't you try out your method on this example?

Comment: What have you tried? For instance, do you know what the eigenvectors are? And I don't mean the concrete formula, I mean more abstractly: what kind of vectors are the eigenvectors of a reflection? What eigenvalues are possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Hint !

The points of the line $L$ are fixed points so, obviously, any vector on the line $L$ is an eigenvector of the eigenvalue $1$. A normal such vector is
$$
v_{(1)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\begin{bmatrix}
b\\-a
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Also, the vectors of the line orthogonal to $L$ (that has equation $bx-ay=0$) are eigenvectors of the eigenvalue $-1$ (can you see why?) and a normal vector of this kind is
$$
v_{(-1)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Can you do from this?